# HTTP error code for "another operation in progress"

Tags: rest, http, http-headers, http-status-codes

My app handles some HTTP requests which needs more time to complete. When request is successfully enqueued, app responds with `202 Accepted` code. However there may be a case when another request is sent while previous one is not completed yet, and app needs to respond with error "another operation in progress" in such case. I checked list of HTTP errors but there is no error with similar description. The closest one which I found is `423 Locked`. Is this the proper error for this case, or some other one would be better?

Answer (score 0):

Http is stateless protocol without cookie/session mechanism. It means one http request doesnot matter with another http. If client and server is under your control, you could add your private status code. BTW 4xx is client side error, 5xx is server side error. 2xx is successful code. In this question , you may define your own 2xx code.

Comment: I control both client and server parts. I need error code for case when server rejects request because previous one for the same resource was not completed

Comment: @DanielFrużyński As far as I know, It seems RFC doesnot exist this kind of status code.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing to me sounds like [503 Service Unavailable](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.4).

- There's nothing wrong with the request
- We want the client to try again later

It's an usual problem to have - why not accept the request and then start work on it when the capacity is available?  But in conditions where that isn't an acceptable option, sending a "I can't do that right now" message seems like a good fit.